# what happened when we use clickonce publishing

Tags: clickonce

Hi All
When We publish a project using ClickOnce what happened step by step.
In other word when we want doing step using command prompt and manually what shoud we do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After your code is compiled, [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28VS.80%29.aspx) is run twice, once to generate a signed `.application` file and once to generate a signed `.deployment` files. After that files are copied to the deployment location (usually a network share).

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983051/publish-clickonce-app-with-msbuild) of interest.

Comment: Thanks but I Don't want changing in the steps.I want Doing steps Manually.In Reality Building a simple Web Page Not Important. I want create setup.exe(without setup.msi) and then build manifests.I can create manifests but not setup.exe.Indeed I want obfuscate out put exe then create setup.exe and manifests with capability of update.

Comment: @Nim I don't get it. Are you talking about building an installer or do you want to do ClickOnce publishing. They are two different things.

Comment: Dear Klaus I want Doing ClickOnce Step Manually.I Want Create setup.exe then generate manifests using mageUI.exe.But I cann't create just setup.exe using Setup Project.Setup Project Create both setup.exe and setup.msi.How I can Create just setup.exe?